# Reproducibility of BIC results in latent class analysis via mclust package in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, mixture-model, mclust

I am conducting a latent class analysis in R using the mclust package. I supplied codes for BIC to select the best fitting model or optimal number of classes, but noticed that the solution is not reproducible since it gives inconsistent output any time I rerun the same codes. For instance as shown below, I initially run the code and it yields a VVV model with 7 classes as the best fitting model. Other candidate best fitting models include VVV,6 and EVE, 8 (shown below):

[image]

I tried running the same code again and it suggests different best fitting models, i.e. EVE,9, EVE,8 and EVI,9 as reported below

[image]

My question is about how to resolve this problem to allow for reproducibility of results. I greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting your seed prior to running your code during testing?
If not, use:

```
set.seed(42) # or whatever number you want...
```

this should allow you to get reproducible results.